# How to create a 3d array in java spring

Tags: java, arrays, spring, arraylist, multidimensional-array

This is my 1st project in java.

I m trying to create a 3D array in Java but failed to do so till now.

I tried multiple ways to create a 3d array. I declared a 3d String array and tried to add elements to it but it didn't work. Also i created a POJO class but i m not sure how to add elements in that.

`{"data":[[{"i1":"1","i2":"2","i3":"3","i4":"4"},{"i1":"5","i2":"6","i3":"7","i4":"8"}],[{"i1":"1","i2":"2","i3":"3","i4":"4"},{"i1":"5","i2":"6","i3":"7","i4":"8"}]]}`

I m calling an API which is returning me some data. Now i want to create a 3D array so that it will be easy in frontend to loop through it.

I tried this :

`String[][][] array = new String[100][][];`

If i do this :

`array[0][0]["i1"] = "1";`

I get error that String can't be converted to int.

I also created a POJO Class :

```
public class Response
{
    private Data[][] data;

    public Data[][] getData ()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData (Data[][] data)
    {
        this.data= data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [data= "+data+"]";
    }
}

public class Data
{
    private String i1;

    private String i2;

    private String i3;

    private String i4;

    public String getI1 ()
    {
        return i1;
    }

    public void setI1 (String i1)
    {
        this.i1 = i1;
    }

    public String getI2 ()
    {
        return i2;
    }

    public void setI2 (String i2)
    {
        this.i2 = i2;
    }

    public String getI3 ()
    {
        return i3;
    }

    public void setI3 (String i3)
    {
        this.i3 = i3;
    }

    public String getI4 ()
    {
        return i4;
    }

    public void setI4 (String i4)
    {
        this.i4 = i4;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [i1 = "+i1+", i2 = "+i2+", i3 = "+i3+", i4 = "+i4+"]";
    }
}
```

But i don't understand how to use this Class.

Please help/guide me solve this.

Thanks

Comment: array[0][0]["i1"] -> between the [ ]'s you're supposed to put the index (which can only be int) not a value

Comment: So what should i do to make a 3d array or can you tell me how to do that using the POJO Class is shared?

Comment: you already have a "3D" array. you just need to figure out how to use them. it's exactly the same as using normal arrays.

Comment: Can you help me out a bit?

Comment: I already told you where you go wrong with your code, and why. what more do you need? start practicing with normal arrays. then, start treating 2D arrays as what they are: normal arrays of which the elements are: normal arrays. same goes for 3D and 2D arrays.

Comment: I tried putting index between []'s and added elements in array like

data[0][0][0] = "test";

I did this but i got an error

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: String[][][] array = new String[100][][]; -> you make it so your array can't have elements (bit weird). try this: String[][][] array = new String[100][100][100]; (or, smaller numbers)

Comment: You can remove the `spring` tag, this question is not related to Spring at all.

Comment: @akuma8 instead of giving an helpful answer, you end up only finding issues in question :) lol

Comment: Some users, like me, receive notifications when a question have a specific tag, so to avoid wasting time, you should aways consider using the best tags for your questions.

Comment: Why do you use SO if you can't answer the questions which belong to your expertise?

Answer (score 0):

you can't code `["i1"]`,you need to code like this,`[0],[1],[2]...`Array's index must be int type ,if you want to create an 3d object array,you should use ArrayList.